# How to set RUBYOPT for only specific RVM versions?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I would like to have `RUBYOPT=-r openssl` set for only my gemsets that are using Ruby 1.9.x. 
Ruby 1.8.x complains "illegal switch in RUBYOPT..." if I have this set globally.

Thank you.

Comment: I've heard that JRuby also checks a seperate environment variable, but I can't google what it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `~/.rvm/hooks/after_use`, put:

```
if echo $rvm_ruby_version | grep -q '1.9'; then
  export RUBYOPT='-r openssl'
else
  export RUBYOPT=
fi
```

Comment: Thank you. Great answer.
Note: I'm not explicitly using a gemset with RVM USE ... I'm relying on the .rvmrc to switch. However .rvmrc doesn't use a 'use' to switch and so doesn't actually fire the after_use hook. I guess I could just change .rvmrc to 'use' instead of what it is doing. Any other thoughts?

Comment: This is not dependent on gemsets or even an explicit use, implicit use also triggers it (eg. `rvm 1.9.2`).  Keep in mind .rvmrc is just a shell script.  I just tested with `rvm 1.9.2` in a project-specific .rvmrc and it worked the same.  Maybe try again with a fresh terminal and if it still fails put some debug `echo`s in your .rvmrc and make sure it's running.

Comment: thanks again. I see the project .rvmrc running when I change directory (put in echos). I put some echos in the after_use and confirmed that it wasn't being called with how my .rvmrc is setting the gemset:

if [[ -d "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments" \
  && -s "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p136@myproj" ]] ; then
  \. "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p136@myproj"
else
...

I confirmed it wasn't running by both absence of echo as well as env does not show RUBYOPT. If I change rvmrc to just rvm use... it works.